# Python Pygame press two direction key and another key to shoot there's no bullet

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a ship shoot a bullet, and everything it works as expected except when I press both <kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>LEFT</kbd> and then <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. Then there's no bullet being fired. There's no bullet being fired for <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>UP</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> either.

However, when I press both <kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> and then <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, it workes. In fact, every other direction key <kbd>LEFT</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN</kbd>, <kbd>UP</kbd> + <kbd>RIGHT</kbd>, <kbd>UP</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN</kbd> works with <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key.

Here's the code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import pygame 

class Setting:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.w = width
        self.h = height
        self.flag = pygame.RESIZABLE
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.speed = 1.5
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.w, self.h), self.flag)
        pygame.display.set_caption("Muhaha")
        self.bullet_s = 1.5
        self.bullet_w = 5
        self.bullet_h = 20
        self.bullet_c = (0, 0, 0)

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, setting, char):
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, setting.bullet_w, setting.bullet_h)
        self.rect.centerx = char.ship_rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = char.ship_rect.top
        self.color = setting.bullet_c
        self.speed = setting.bullet_s
        self.y = float(self.rect.centery)
    
    def move_bullet(self):
        self.y -= self.speed
        self.rect.y = self.y
    
    def draw_bullet(self, setting):
        pygame.draw.rect(setting.screen, self.color, self.rect)

    def blit_bullet(self, bullets, setting):
        for bullet in bullets.sprites():
             pygame.draw.rect(setting.screen, bullet.color, bullet.rect)
             bullet.y -= bullet.speed
             bullet.rect.y = bullet.y
       

class Char:
    def __init__(self, screen, setting):
        bk = pygame.image.load("image/muha.png").convert()
        self.bkg = pygame.transform.smoothscale(bk, (setting.w, setting.h))
        temp = pygame.image.load("image/title.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.ship = pygame.transform.smoothscale(temp, (200, 200))
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.ship_rect = self.ship.get_rect()

        self.ship_rect.center = self.screen_rect.center
        self.ship_rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
       
        self.x = float(self.ship_rect.centerx)
        self.y = float(self.ship_rect.centery)

    def blit_screen(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.bkg, (0, 0))
    
    def blit_ship(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.ship, self.ship_rect)

        
class Check_event:
     def __init__(self):
        self.moving_up   = False
        self.moving_down = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_right = False
     
     def event(self, bullets, setting, char):      
         for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                 sys.exit()
             elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                 if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullets.add(Bullet(setting, char))
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                     self.moving_up = True
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                     self.moving_down = True
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                     self.moving_left = True
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                     self.moving_right = True

             elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                 if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                     self.moving_up = False
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                     self.moving_down = False
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                     self.moving_left = False
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                     self.moving_right = False

     def move(self, setting, char):
         if self.moving_up == True and char.ship_rect.top >= 0:
            char.y -= setting.speed
         if self.moving_down == True and char.ship_rect.bottom <= setting.h:
             char.y += setting.speed
         if self.moving_left == True and char.ship_rect.left >= 0:
             char.x -= setting.speed
         if self.moving_right == True and char.ship_rect.right <= setting.w:
             char.x += setting.speed
             # press both "up" &"left" then press "space"
         char.ship_rect.centerx = char.x
         char.ship_rect.centery = char.y

def game():
    pygame.init()
    setting = Setting(1200, 800)
    screen = setting.screen 
    char = Char(screen, setting)
    check_event = Check_event()
    bullet = Bullet(setting, char)
    bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
                      

    while True:
        check_event.event(bullets, setting, char)
        
        char.blit_screen()
        check_event.event(bullets, setting, char)
        check_event.move(setting, char)
        bullet.blit_bullet(bullets, setting)
        
        char.blit_ship()
        pygame.display.flip()
game()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you press <kbd>UP</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> then the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key doesn't appear to be pressed immediately. You've to release the <kbd>UP</kbd> or <kbd>LEFT</kbd> key to get the `pygame.KEYDOWN` event for <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

This is a known bug in pygame and doesn't seem to be solved yet: [Incorrect handling of pressed keys #235](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/235)

Sadly even [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) doesn't state the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key in this case, so I can't even think a workaround.

Comment: but "right"+"up"+"space" is worked,"left"+"up"+"space" is not worked,so that is a bug in pygame right? BTW how to input "left"+"up"+"space" as you like a really keyboard ...

Comment: @M_Sea Yes exactly, that's the bug. It is expleind in the link in detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot i try to instead "space" to any other key ,it worked,