# Issue with multi keys being pressed at once for two player game

Tags: python, pygame, keypress

I am not sure if it is my coding or just my computers limitations but I seem to have issue with multiple keys being pressed in a two player game. The keys themselves work correctly and as I want them too, but since two players could be pressing 4 keys simultaneously (say <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>LEFT</kbd>) if they are both speeding forward and want to dodge something left or right, it seems that one of the keys will not work for one of the players if all 4 are being pressed at same time.... 'left' (<kbd>A</kbd>) will suddenly work if `player1` releases 'up' (<kbd>W</kbd>) - this is while simultaneously `player2` is pressing 'up' (<kbd>UP</kbd>) and say right (<kbd>RIGHT</kbd>)

Is there a better way to ask for key event / pressed for this to stop happening or is my code ok and maybe my computer is just lagging?

```py
keystate1 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keystate1[pygame.K_a]:
    self.speedx = -5
if keystate1[pygame.K_d]:
    self.speedx = 5
if keystate1[pygame.K_w]:
    self.speedy = -5
if keystate1[pygame.K.s]:
    self.speedy = 5
```

Same would go for `player2` except [K.LEFT, K.RIGHT, K.UP, K.DOWN]

Any help would be appreciated

Upon further testing it only seems to happen to `player1` pressing <kbd>A</kbd> when both `player1` & `player2` are pressing up (<kbd>W</kbd> & <kbd>UP</kbd>) at same time... then `player1` won't move left unless `player1` lets go of <kbd>W</kbd> or player2 lets go of <kbd>UP</kbd>.
It doesn't affect `player2` at all (<kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>DOWN</kbd>, <kbd>LEFT</kbd>, <kbd>RIGHT</kbd>) or any other direction of `player1` except left <kbd>A</kbd>?

Comment: It seems to be a hardware limitation of the keyboard, see [How do I remove the limit on PC keyboard button presses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses). The only pygame issue I know, is related to the space button, see [Python Pygame press two direction key and another key to shoot there's no bullet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59004524/python-pygame-press-two-direction-key-and-another-key-to-shoot-theres-no-bullet/59005776#59005776)

Comment: Thanks. After doing some more reading myself on the hardware limitation it looks like one has to look for keyboards with 6KRO, 10KRO or NKRO... with the 6,10 or N indicating how many keys can be pressed without “ghosting”. Most standard keyboards are set up with multiple keys in one circuit for cost savings so that is why you can only press so many keys before it can’t take any more input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hardware limitation of your keyboard. Most of them will not be able to register 4 non-modifier keys being pressed at the same time due to the way they are manufactured

Comment: Thanks. After doing some more reading myself on the hardware limitation it looks like one has to look for keyboards with 6KRO, 10KRO or NKRO... with the 6,10 or N indicating how many keys can be pressed without “ghosting”. Most standard keyboards are set up with multiple keys in one circuit for cost savings so that is why you can only press so many keys before it can’t take any more input.