# PyGame not registering a third key press

Tags: python, pygame, keypress

I'm making my first pygame project and it has been going smoothly. I wrote the following code to check for inputs and so far it was working ok.

```
   def check_events(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.running, self.playing = False, False
            self.curr_menu = False
            self.curr_level.run_level = False
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.DOWN_KEY = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.UP_KEY = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                self.START_KEY = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE or event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                self.BACK_KEY = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.LEFT_KEY = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.RIGHT_KEY = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                self.SPACE_KEY = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RSHIFT or event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                self.SHIFT_KEY = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.DOWN_KEY = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.UP_KEY = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                self.START_KEY = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE or event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                self.BACK_KEY = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.LEFT_KEY = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.RIGHT_KEY = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                self.SPACE_KEY = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RSHIFT or event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                self.SHIFT_KEY = False
```

I wanted to add a sprinting for the `x (SHIFT)` and `y (SPACE)` axis it doesn't work properly. Whenever hold down `SPACE` and `RIGHT`, `pygame` doesn't register the `UP` key getting pressed and whenever I hold `SPACE` and `LEFT`, `pygame` doesn't register both `UP` and `DOWN`.
Somehow, holding shift doesn't mess with the registration of the arrow keys.

Because of the issues I was experiencing with the sprinting I started investigating further and realized that `pygame` doesn't recognize me pressing the `UP` key when `LEFT` and `RIGHT` are pressed simultaneously, but recognizes the `DOWN` key press.

Is the problem in my code?

Comment: There is a known bug. See [Python Pygame press two direction key and another key to shoot there's no bullet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59004524/python-pygame-press-two-direction-key-and-another-key-to-shoot-theres-no-bullet/59005776#59005776)

Comment: Switching from the arrow keys to WASD fixed the issue, thank you @Rabbid76 .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with pressed events you need to use:

```
pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

It returns the state of the key is pressed or not (True, False)

Example:

```
key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key_pressed[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:
    sprintX()
if key_pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    sprintY()
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw the .`get_pressed` function and integrated it, it's more elegant for sure, but it didn't fix my problem, so I reverted to the old code.

Comment: I got it. I read the related issue of pygame, and it seems that it is directly related to keyboard limitations for special keys. https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/235#issuecomment-451767238. using another keys(wasd) for move is sensible in this situation